# Postgres query to get particular text from given text

Tags: postgresql, extract

I have text like this in different rows in a column

- xxxxxxxxxxx ab_88_2018 xxxxxx
- ab_88_2018 xxxxxx
- AB_88_2018 xxxxxx
- ab_2018_88 XXXXXX

So I want only 88 out of the text into another column. 
What can be the query?

Its not 88, but two numbers in that position

Comment: What did you try so far? Please edit the question and add your existing attempt. It is also unclear exactly what you want, so provide a clear example of what you want the output to look like.

Comment: If you only want 88, then how does it differ from returning a hardcoded 88 in the select?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want. Just the value `88`? Or a value of two numeric digits delimited by underscores and/or spaces? Please [edit] your question and explain the rules a bit better

Comment: What if  value is: `xxxxxx_33_xxx ab_88_2018 xxxxxx`, then what is expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the 88 always a 2 digit number? If so, this is working for me for Postgres and Redshift and I believe gets you what you want:

```
SELECT
CASE
  WHEN LOWER(column)
    ~ '.*[a-z]{2}\_[0-9]{2}\_[0-9]{4}.*' THEN SPLIT_PART(column,'_',2)
  WHEN LOWER(column)
    ~ '[a-z]{2}\_[0-9]{4}\_[0-9]{2}.*' THEN LEFT(SPLIT_PART(column,'_',3),2)
    END As get_two_digit_number
```

The ~ (tilde) is similar to LIKE but allows you to do pattern matching through regex. See regexr.com and paste your examples and the code between the '' to see what it's matching

SPLIT_PART is taking the string that matches the pattern, and then breaking it on a character of my choosing, here it's the '_'. The last number is which break to return

Using 'xxxxxxxxxxx ab_88_2018 xxxxxx' as an example, SPLIT_PART('xxxxxxxxxxx ab_88_2018 xxxxxx','*',2) will return '88'as 88 is the second part after '*'. If you entered 1 it would return everything *before* the '_'

Comment: Notice the use of LOWER to convert all your text into lower case before matching, this prevents the need to run duplicate CASE WHENs for AB and ab in your strings